# Hiding class based on radio selection

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to hide a class based on the name (etc. "hiddenA"), I previously used ID but I want to hide more than 1 class so ID is no longer an option. This is what I have currently:

```js
function onChangePackage() {
    const nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('Package');
    var selectedValue;
    // Get selected radio
    for (var i = 0, length = nodes.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].checked) {
            selectedValue = nodes[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Showing all nodes first
    const nodePostFix = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
    nodePostFix.forEach(node => {
        const currentElement = elementsToHide.item(i);
        if (currentElement.hasClass('hidden' + selectedValue)) {
            currentElement.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            currentElement.style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
}
```

I feel like I am over complicating my code as there surely must be a simpler way.

Comment: When `onChangePackage` gets called?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code here. You will just have to change the button to a radio button. Also use jquery. I think this is what you wanted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#p1, #p2").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Hide / Show</button>

<p id="p1">I have a class of p1</p>
<p id="p2"s>I have a class of p2</p>
<p id="p1">I have a class of p1</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And magically, jQuery! Seriously though, this is a completely unnecessary use of jQuery and it's not needed at all.

Comment: @Aplet: that seems somewhat reasonable since the OP is using the [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method of the jQuery library. Yes, I agree it's overkill for this particular use but if it's already available to the OP then why not?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Oh I didn't see that. I guess you're right then.